# Differences between {beg / beg for / beg of / beg from}

Tags: prepositions, verbs, phrasal-verbs

How do these phrases differ from each other, and how should they be used?

> 1. I **beg** you to keep quiet.
> 2. I **beg for** you to keep quiet.
> 3. I **beg from** you to keep quiet.
> 4. I **beg of** you to keep quiet.

Answer (score 4):

> I beg you to keep quiet.

This is the **present** form of the verb.  This means that you are currently begging me to keep quiet.

> I beg for you to keep quiet.

The meaning of this is identical to the **present** form of the verb.

> I beg from you to keep quiet.

To my knowledge this is not correct (or if it is technically correct, it is very uncommon).

> I beg of you to keep quiet

This is can be used in the same situations as the first two phrases.  This one will more commonly be used as a direct statement to the person you are talking to.  The first two are generally not used when speaking directly to a person.

Comment: Note that people don't actually say these things.

Comment: Sure they do say these things.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to start by pointing out that the average native English speaking person would not use this form when asking someone to be quiet. Generally we simply say "Please be quiet" or "shut up" (rude) or "hush".

This form was much more common in English a [couple of centuries ago](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20beg%20you%2CI%20beg%20for%20you%2CI%20beg%20from%20you%2CI%20beg%20of%20you&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20beg%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20beg%20for%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20beg%20from%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20beg%20of%20you%3B%2Cc0) but it has dropped out of popularity.

---

Now, as to the general correctness of the phrases.

The only two that are truly correct English are the first and (almost) the last:

> I beg you to keep quiet.

This is the standard way of phrasing this statement. You can also omit "to":

> I beg you, keep quiet.

The last one is almost OK but even when it's fixed, it's even more antiquated that the previous form.

> I beg of you, keep quiet.

Even with this form, I don't believe the "to" would generally be included.

The other two are simply wrong for this form:

> I beg for...

This should be used when there's an object:

> I beg for money from my parents.
>   I beg for release from my life of misery.

And then there's

> I beg from...

This one needs a range or a group:

> I beg from dawn to dusk.
>   I beg from the rich.