# What is the difference between "disapprove" and "disapprove of"?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-structure, transitivity

Does adding "of" makes any difference in the sentences?

For example:

> He disapproved of people marrying more than once.

Can't I write in following way?

> He disapproved **the** people...

Another question related to this: Is there any difference between these two?

> I beg you.
>
> I beg of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you **disapprove of** someone or something, you simply have a negative opinion of it:

> My mother **disapproves of** the woman I am seeing.

When you **disapprove** something, you reject something, usually having the official power to do so:

> The principal **disapproved** the students' request for less homework.

Based on this second definition, it is less likely that you would disapprove people, rather than things.  But you might:

> The mayor **disapproved** the new nominee for dogcatcher.

Conversely, if you added **of**, the mayor would just be offering a personal opinion, not officially rejecting the nominee:

> The mayor **disapproved of** the new nominee for dogcatcher.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example,

> He *disapproved of* people marrying more than once.

uses the following definition of disapprove:

> To have an unfavorable opinion; express disapproval (usually followed by of).

Your second example,

> He *disapproved* the people...

uses the following definition of disapprove:

> To withhold approval from; decline to sanction.

While it is possible to *approve* and *disapprove* individuals, in most contexts (and including your example), to *approve of* and *disapprove of* people is appropriate.

Source: [Random House Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disapprove)

---

Your question regarding *beg* has been answered here:

[Differences between {beg / beg for / beg of / beg from}](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68661/differences-between-beg-beg-for-beg-of-beg-from)

Comment: Still couldn't understand. Would you please elaborate it more? And does it make any difference if I write "disapprove people" instead of "disapprove the people"?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary gives more information about
*to approve*/*to disapprove*:

**BrE**: [to disapprove **of** somebody/something](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/disapprove) and to disapprove.

> 1. She wants to be an actress, but her parents disapprove.
> 2. He strongly **disapproved of the changes** that had been made.

**AmE** as in BrE  but *to disapprove of somebody/something* has a variant:
[to **disapprove somebody**/something](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/disapprove)

> 1. A solid majority **disapproves the way** the president is handling the controversy.

As to the verb construction BrE is conservative.  Only AmE dares to get away from the genitive construction by dropping "of".

Comment: Interesting, the second usage isn't correct in my AmE dialect. I'm not discounting your response in any way, just commenting that I find it interesting sometimes when usage varies drastically not just among varieties of English, but among regions in the same variety as well.

Answer (score 0):

*Disapprove* is not usually used with an object (in contrast to *approve* which often is).

It's because you don't take action by saying you disapprove of X, but you are expressing how you feel about X.

In business settings and similar it's common to use *approve* with an object, e.g. *I approved time for this project*, but the opposite of *approve* in that context is not *disapprove* but *do not approve* - *I did not approve time for this project.*

So you cannot omit the *of*.

---

> I beg you [to do X, for X].

You are begging someone to do something.

> I beg of you [to do X, for X].

You are begging someone to let you use a resource they have or control.  You're not technically really directly "begging" the person you are talking to.

As a person's ability to directly help you can be considered a resource, and "doing something" can involve letting someone use a resource one has, the distinction between these doesn't matter much.

*I beg of you* has the connotation of sounding much more formal and polite, and somewhat archaic.

Comment: Okay, what is the difference between "consider" and "consider as"?
Or is it just a typo?